# Trying to setup phpUnderControl but missing phpcb

Tags: php, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I'm trying to setup phpUnderControl on Ubuntu 10.04 following this tutorial http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/03/03/getting-started-with-phpundercontrol/. I get to the part where it says to type in `sudo phpuc example /opt/cruisecontrol` but recieve the following error: Missing cli tool 'phpcb', check the PATH variable. I did a little googling but can't seem to find reference of a phpcb anywhere. Does anyone know what this is and where I might get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The missing cli tool 'phpcb' is a PHP Code Browser, not a beautifier.  You install it using pear, from the same repository as phpunit:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeBrowser
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694985/phpundercontrol-and-codebrowser

Comment: the correct version is now:  pear install --alldeps phpqatools/PHP_CodeBrowser

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that it's phpCodeBeautifier (http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/). In case anyone runs across this in the future with this same problem I just downloaded it and copied the file in /bin and I had to rename it from phpCB to phpcb.